# Select option from dropdown where attribute or second value contains string

Tags: jquery

There are multiple drop down list controls in one div, both have same id for some reasons. I want to select an option of each drop down control on button click event where value2 = 'selected'.

I have tried this so far without any luck;

Here is the Html code;

```js
$('#btnSelectVal').click(function(e) {
  $("#localCartData").find("select option[value2$='selected']").attr('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='localCartData'>


<select id="ddlList">
  <option value="3" value2="">Three</option>
  <option value="1" value2="selected">One</option> 
  <option value="Order_0" value2="">Zero</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id="ddlList">
  <option value="3" value2="">Three</option>
  <option value="1" value2="">One</option>
  <option value="Order_0" value2="selected">Zero</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>

</div>

<input type="button" id="btnSelectVal" Value=" Select Value " />
```

Comment: first thing: You have two elements with same id `ddlList`, this is invalid HTML. for element properties that are not default, use `data-`, like `data-value2="..."`

Comment: yes i am aware of it and it can't be changed. Thanks, i will look into data-value attributes.

Comment: ok, but to fix your problem, fix the id of `localCartData`, remove the "#" on the start of the id, it should be: `<div id='localCartData'>` to jQuery selector be able to find it

Comment: You also should use `.prop` instead of `.attr` for selected, since it can end up causing troubles since you cannot remove it with as attribute only as property.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comments i updated the value2 attribute to data-status and changed the jquery code to fix this issue.

```js
$('#btnSortVal').click(function(e) {

  $('#localCartData select option').each(function() {  
      if($(this).data('status') == 'selected'){
            $(this).attr('selected', true); 
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='localCartData'>


<select id="ddlList">
  <option value="3" data-status="">Three</option>
  <option value="1" data-status="selected">One</option>
  <option value="Order_0" data-status="">Zero</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id="ddlList">
  <option value="3" data-status="">Three</option>
  <option value="1" data-status="">One</option>
  <option value="Order_0" data-status="selected">Zero</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>

</div>

<input type="button" id="btnSortVal" Value=" Sort Dropdown By Value " />
```